# Merge two shell scripts using conditional operators or using if statements

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am new to Bash shell scripting and I have two scripts running in AWS EC2 as cronjobs.

First script is running as cronjob to copy the MySQL database backup daily to S3 and the script is running in the server on 12.10am every day.

```
#!/bin/bash
DAY_2=`(date --date='1 days ago' '+%m-%d-%y')`
cd /home/mysqlbackup/
tar -czvf $DAY_2.tgz /home/mysqlbackup/$DAY_2
s3cmd put /home/mysqlbackup/$DAY_2.tgz s3://mysql_backup/ubuntu/
```

Second script is also running as a cronjob on the same server to monitor the disk space of the server. This script is run every 4 hours.

```
#!/bin/sh
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
  echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
  if [ $usep -ge 85 ]; then
    echo "Running Out Of Space On Mysql Backup Server \"$partition and Space Used ($usep%)\" On $(hostname) As On $(date)"|
    /usr/bin/mail -s  "Alert: Almost Out Of Disk Space. Space Used  $usep%" xxx@example.com
  fi
done
```

So the problem is I have these scripts running separately. I need a single script which will monitor the disk space of the server and as the result whenever disk space usage reaches over 85% it should automatically copy the MySQL database backup to S3 automatically and if the disk space usage is below 85% means the script should normally copy the MySQL databases backup on everyday 12.10am.

I am not able combine these two scripts into a single script as my programming skills are very limited. So I am posting in Stack Overflow to seek professional help to accomplish the above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do ***not*** combine the scripts -- that way is the path to madness.  Modify the disk space checking script to invoke the backup script when a backup is needed.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response. can you help me how and where should i invoke the backup script.

Comment: After the `/usr/bin/mail` line, add `/where/you/keep/your/backup-cronscript` as an extra command.